# SQL Query WHERE equals int or varchar without breaking?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when, sql-convert

There is an instance where the filters I have are being dynamically plugged into my SQL query and sometimes cannot tell prior if they are `int` or `varchar`. Is there a way to allow either with a `CASE WHEN` statement?

In my table (`ent` for entity), the column company is a string/`varchar` and the `entid` column is an `int`. I cannot seem to get this `CASE IsNumeric` statement to work for cases when an int is the filter, or the string is the filter.

This works:

```
select 
    ent.company 
from 
    ent 
where 
    ent.company in
         (CASE 
             WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.')) = 0 
               THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.') 
               ELSE '99' 
          END,
          CASE 
             WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'Schulte Building Systems')) = 0 
               THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'Schulte Building Systems') 
               ELSE '1423' 
          END)
```

[image]

This is **not** working:

```
select 
    ent.company 
from 
    ent 
where 
    ent.entid in 
        (CASE 
            WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.')) = 0 
              THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.') 
              ELSE '99' 
         END,
         CASE 
            WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'Schulte Building Systems')) = 0 
              THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'Schulte Building Systems') 
              ELSE '1423' 
         END)
```

[image]

...but for the int equals if I change the 0's to 1's it works (and if I use company equals, it returns nothing). Any idea why it's failing?

Comment: Show execution plan for both, I assume there is cast before `CASE` take place.

Comment: This is the entire query, no cast. What are you asking for?

Comment: I mean [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/image_6E693012.png), not your queries but how query optimizer will execute them

Comment: How do you suggest I change then then?

Comment: Never mind, in second query in CASE you return `NVARCHAR` and you compare with `INT` which cause this error.

Comment: In your case statement return always numbers `WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.')) = 0 
              THEN **CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 'ABIS, Inc.')** - change to INT id not string 
              ELSE '99' `

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was never asking about the actual column - just the filter.

```
select ent.entid, ent.company from ent where 

ent.entid in
(
    CASE IsNumeric(entid) WHEN 1 then '99' else 'ABIS, Inc.' End,
    CASE IsNumeric(entid) WHEN 1 then '1423' else 'Schulte Building Systems' End    
)
```

and

```
select ent.entid, ent.company from ent where 

ent.company in
(
    CASE IsNumeric(company) WHEN 1 then '99' else 'ABIS, Inc.' End,
    CASE IsNumeric(company) WHEN 1 then '1423' else 'Schulte Building Systems' End  
)
```

both work.